# index.php not displaying. displays error page instead

Tags: php, validation

i have a page with 4 links namely 1st.php, 2nd.php, 3rd.php, and 4th.php. my index.php displays the 3rd.php as default. i also created a 404.php (error page) so that when a user edits the URL it will not redirect to the index.php, instead it will display the error page. the problem is when i open my index.php page, it displays the error page instead. need help. this is my code:

```
 <?php 

  $quarters = array('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4');
        $quarter = 'Q3';

        if(isset($_GET['quarter']) && in_array($_GET['quarter'], $quarters)) {
          $quarter = $_GET['quarter'];  
        }

        switch($quarter) {
          case 'Q1' :
            $quarter = 'firstq2012.php';
          break;
          case 'Q2' :
            $quarter = 'secondq2012.php';
          break;
          case 'Q3' :
            $quarter = 'thirdq2012.php';
          break;
          case 'Q4' :
            $quarter = 'fourthq2012.php';
          break;
        }

    $pages = array('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4');
    if (in_array($_GET['quarter'], $pages)){            
                    include_once $quarter;  
 }
 else {
 header('Location: 404.php');
  }
?>
```

Comment: logic , before and after `switch` are similar. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: what is the advantage of having 2 of the same arrays with different names ?

Comment: when i remove the if after the switch and the user types random input in the url, it displays the index page. but if i dont remove it, anything the user input in the url besides my files, redirects to the error page.

Comment: You use too much code. :-) $pages and $quarters contain the same.
Anyway: DO you call this page like: http://www.example.com/yourscriptname.php?quarter=Q2 ?

Comment: @erwin yes i do call it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be cleaned up a lot.

Try using this intead:

```
<?php 
$quarters = array('Q1' => 'firstq2012.php', 'Q2' => 'secondq2012.php', 'Q3' => 'thirdq2012.php', 'Q4' => 'fourthq2012.php');
if(isset($_GET['quarter'])) {
    if(in_array($_GET['quarter'], array_keys($quarters))) {
        include_once $quarters[$_GET['quarter']];
    } else {
        header('Location: 404.php');
    }
} else {
    include_once $quarters['Q3'];
}
?>
```

Comment: wow this nailed it. sorry for a noob question and noob codes structure. beginner here. thanks!

Comment: EDIT: if i type localhost/test/index.php?quarte or something like that, it still displays the index.php page.

Comment: @jet - Do you mean that it doesn't include any files, or even redirect to the error page?

Comment: no. anything you type as long as the 'index.php?' is intact. it still displays the index page. i typed in  index.php?sdafafasdfa and it just displays the index page. but the other thing that worked is the one when i input index.php?quarter=Q5 and above, displays the error page.

Comment: @jet - It works fine for me, is there anything else in your script that could be causing a problem?

Comment: what i mean is if you type a link besides the index.php and the other 4 files, it should display the error page. hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Why do You add GET data to quarter if after that You re-initialize $quarter?
And re-initialized $quarter stores incorrect filenames, if You have 1st.php not firstq2012.php.
And `if (in_array($_GET['quarter'], $pages)){

                    include_once $quarter;

 }
 else {
 header('Location: 404.php');
  }`
If $_GET['quarter'] does not exists, which would be if opens just index.php not index.php?q=..., then it redirects.
I suggest that in Your switch...case You create variable $filename = '1st.php';
And then check `if (in_array($quarter, $pages)) { include_once $filename; } else { ... }`

Comment: actually 1st.php and firstq2012.php are the same, i just shortcut it. sorry for the confusion.